# .NET framework upgrade guidelines

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks, upgrade

I have an application with the minimum system requirement of .`NET Version as 4.5`. Now I need to upgrade one of the dependencies of my project which requires a `higher version` of the .NET framework. Here say the new .NET framework version as  `4.5.2`.

So Increasing the `Target framework` version to 4.5.2 in my project and suggest my users upgrade theirs .NET framework version to 4.5.2 is only needed or something I need to check further.

> My question is **What are the details one need to check before upgrading the .NET framework of the project**.

Comment: Kindly Migrate the question to any other Stack exchange website if it needs to be moved.

Comment: In my understanding you just need to check that the other dependencies for your project works in 4.5.2.
If you have an installation project, you can always link as dependency the framework, so whenever the user is installing it (or upgrading it) the correct framework will be download in case the clien doesn't have it

Comment: @Venkat, Did you resolved this issue? As you said that you will update dependencies for your project, if your current project requires higher .NET Framework, how did you run it in your side before you deploy it to your customer's environment? If you have installed the .NET Framework 4.5.2, you would suggest you customer to install it. Or if it just needs to use certain dll file, you could just include it in your setup package. If I have misunderstood this issue, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the .NET Framework is designed to maximize backward compatibility.
Especially upgrading to a later point release rarely causes any issues.

However, always check whether the new .NET Framework version is still supported by your (minimum) target Windows version? See [.NET Framework system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements)

Note that some of your dependencies might have another version available, which target the newer .NET Framework version, profiting from new features. See [upgrade NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages).

Here is the complete guide: [Migration Guide to the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/)